# LotusScript: nested if statements?

Tags: lotusscript

Translating lotusScript and I'm not sure if these if statements are nested or not

```
If doc.Ventilation(0) = "Power" Then
    If doc.TypeInlet(0) = "8'' Continious" Or doc.TypeInlet(0) = "12'' 
    Continious" Then
    num_inlet_rows = doc.Width(0) \ inlet_row
         If doc.Width(0) Mod inlet_row > .4 Then num_inlet_rows = 
         num_inlet_rows + 1
         If num_inlet_rows Mod 2 <> 0 Then num_inlet_rows = num_inlet_rows+1 
         If (num_inlets_power / num_inlet_rows) > doc.Length(0) Then 
         num_inlet_rows = num_inlet_rows + 2
    Else
         l = 11
         While (doc.Length(0) / num_inlet_columns) < ((doc.Width(0) / 
         num_inlet_rows) / 1.20) And (l > 0)
              l = l - 1
              num_inlet_rows = num_inlet_rows + 1
         Wend
    End If
    ...
End If
```

[Here's the code, couldn't figure out how to format correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laMek.png)

Comment: please don't forget to upvote the answers and accept one of them as correct, if the helped you... Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two types of if- statements in Lotusscript.

The first one is written in ONE LINE without a line break. It does not need an end if statement and closes with the end of the line. It does NOT nest.

```
If x = 3 then y = y + 1 else y = y - q
```

Is an example for these „oneliners“. 
This statement is complete as is and has no other code nested in it. you can even omit the else- case as in your example code.

The second one is in more than one line. It needs an end if statement to be complete:

```
If x = 4 then
  y = y + 1
Else
  y = y - 1
End if
```

Is exactly the same, but here you can put more code between then if and else and end if: it can be nested.

That said: your. Ode is both, partly nested and partly not. I think, you can identify yourself now, which is which.

Answer (score 0):

You missed one `End If` statement:

```
If doc.Ventilation(0) = "Power" Then
    If doc.TypeInlet(0) = "8'' Continious" Or doc.TypeInlet(0) = "12'' Continious" Then
        num_inlet_rows = doc.Width(0) \ inlet_row
        If doc.Width(0) Mod inlet_row > .4 Then num_inlet_rows = num_inlet_rows + 1
        If num_inlet_rows Mod 2 <> 0 Then num_inlet_rows = num_inlet_rows+1 
        If (num_inlets_power / num_inlet_rows) > doc.Length(0) Then 
            num_inlet_rows = num_inlet_rows + 2
        Else
            l = 11
            While (doc.Length(0) / num_inlet_columns) < ((doc.Width(0) / num_inlet_rows) / 1.20) And (l > 0)
                l = l - 1
                num_inlet_rows = num_inlet_rows + 1
            Wend
        End If
        '...
    End If
End If
```